# Session Should be cleared on closing the browser

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Web Application built on Blazor Server .Net Core 5 with Azure AD B2C as authentication, When the session is active and when we close the broswer, On re opening the link the screen is automatically log din without asking for credentials, So My requirement is on closing browser all the tokens needs to be cleared and re login should be prompted

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with the default configuration without KMSI (Keep-me signed in) the behavior is what you expect, i.e. session is cleared and user is forced to reauthenticate.

I've just confirmed this on my custom policies with default session behavior. As long as I have a browser opened, I'm rauthenticated without prompt. As soon as I close the browser and open it again, Azure AD B2C prompts me for sign in.